# A property similar to compactly packed

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

An ideal $I$ of a commutative ring $R$ is said to be compactly packed by prime ideals if whenever $I$ is contained in the union of a family of prime ideals of $R$, then $I$ is actually contained in one of the prime ideals of the family. Now  I want to know that is there any study or mane for the property that if $I$  contains  the intersection of a family of ideals of $R$, then $I$  contains  one of them. (It seems to be the dual concept of compactly packed or an extention of prime ideal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a search for "dual to compactly packed ring" and found this:

> [ÖZKİRİŞCİ, NESLİHAN AYŞEN, KÜRŞAT HAKAN ORAL, and ÜNSAL TEKİR. "On coprimely structured rings." Turkish Journal of Mathematics 40.4 (2016): 719-727.](http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/math/issues/mat-16-40-4/mat-40-4-1-1502-28.pdf)

In the introduction, we can find:

> Gilmer formed the dual notion of compactly packed rings in his paper
>   ”An Intersection Condition for Prime Ideals” and studied some properties of this notion [6]

Where reference [6] is

> Gilmer R. An intersection condition for prime ideals. Lect Notes Pure Appl 1997; 189: 327-331.

Unfortunately I could not quickly find the text for this online, so I haven't determined what he called them yet.

*Update:* I finally got my hands on the Gilmer paper. His condition is:

> For any nonempty family of ideals $\{I_\alpha|\alpha\in A\}$ and prime ideal $P$, $\cap_{\alpha\in A} I_\alpha\subseteq P\implies I_\beta\subseteq P$ for some $\beta$.

Gilmer showed that the commutative rings satisfying this condition for all nonempty families of ideals and all prime ideals are exactly the zero-dimensional semilocal rings (semilocal means finitely many maximal ideals.)

---

Finally, I'd like to make sure you realize that this dual condition you are talking about is **not an extension** of prime ideals. Prime ideals satisfy this condition for finite families, but they may fail the condition for infinite families. For example, the prime ideal $\{0\}\lhd \mathbb Z$ satisfies $\bigcap\{ (p)\mid p\in\mathbb Z, p \text{ prime }\}\subseteq \{0\}$, but of course no one $(p)$ is contained in $\{0\}$.

An ideal satisfying your condition is not even necessarily prime. For example, in $\mathbb R[x]/(x^3)$, the ideal $I$ generated by $x^2$ is minimal, and obviously satisfies the condition (There are only four ideals: any intersection of ideals contained in $I$ would have to have $I$ or $\{0\}$ as one of its members.)

So, there is no axiomatic connection with prime ideals, although some additional conditions added may demonstrate some other connection.